# Spring boot Swagger annotation to link another end-point in swagger ui api doc

Tags: spring-boot, swagger

I have a microservice project built using spring boot, which exposes an endpoint which say is version1.

Now, I need to add a link to the v2 endpoint and deprecate v1, so in Swagger UI the v1 will be linked in the deprecated section.

I  deprecate the version1 using @Deprecate java annotation, but not sure if there is an annotation that i can use to link the new endpoint on version1 so the Swagger UI api doc will display the link.

say,

```
# deprecated - refer the new end-point link
my-app/endpoint/v1


# new version of end-point
my-app/endpoint/v2
```

Comment: Are you using springfox or springdoc or anything else?

Comment: Using `springdoc-openapi`

Comment: You can split v1 and v2 into different groups -> https://dev.to/s2agrahari/grouping-apis-in-swagger-55kk

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the perfect answer but closest to what I needed.

When using V1 and V2, it is better to use the approach suggested by @meridbt

- From the Openapi documentation, Links server different purpose. If the existing endpoint is using another endpoint to fetch info, we use link.
- For my scenario, i used the Links option in the `@Operation` annoation

```java
@Operation(summary = "Wished hello", operationId = "requestMessage", responses = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "OK", links = {
                    @Link(name = "hello", operationId = "SayHello", parameters = {
                            @LinkParameter(name = "message", expression = "$request.query.message"),
                    })
            })
    })
    @Deprecated(since = "0.0.1", forRemoval = true)
    @GetMapping("/greet/{message}")
    public String getGreetings(@PathVariable String message) {
        return "hello World";
    }
    
    /**
     * Below is the new endpoint, which needs to be used
     */
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String getHello(String message) {
        return "Hello from the serever";
    }
```

[image: Link displays the details of other end point]